# "auto" type not deduced in clang libtooling 3.8.1

Tags: c++11, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang, libtooling

I am using clang 3.8.1 libtooling library. I have written visitor for c++ auto types. When I try to get the deduced type I get NULL-TYPE.

Did anybody face a similar issue?
Please enlighten me on auto type deduction in clang as it is leading me nowhere.

sample code:

```
bool ASTPrinter::VisitAutoTypeLoc(AutoTypeLoc TL) { 

std::string deducedTypeSig = TL.getType().getAsString(); 

if (TL.getTypePtr()->isDeduced()) { 
  deducedTypeSig = TL.getTypePtr()->getDeducedType().getAsString(); 
 } 
}
```

Comment: Any code to share?

Comment: `bool ASTPrinter::VisitAutoTypeLoc(AutoTypeLoc TL)
{
 std::string deducedTypeSig = TL.getType().getAsString();

 if (TL.getTypePtr()->isDeduced())
 {
  deducedTypeSig = TL.getTypePtr()->getDeducedType().getAsString();
 }
}`

Comment: In the above snippet, isDeduced() always return false.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the code and explanation into the question instead of posting a hard-to-read one-liner in comments? Ideally provide a [mcve].